# How to pass list from jsp to servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to pass a list from jsp to servlet? I want to add the dianomic field in my JSP and insert it through a servlet.

Comment: provide what you have tried?

Comment: Do you mean passing from form to servlet?

Comment: please take your time to read how to write a [mcve], that will help a lot for asking nice questions and getting helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

Use `session.setAttribute(String name, Object value)` within the JSP, then retrieve it using `session.getAttribute(String name)` in the servlet.